# Finding the value of data-attribute inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

How can I find(detect) the value of a data attribute in a bootstrap carousel.

For example

```
<div class="item" data-slide-number="2" data-nexttopic="T0024">

                    <div class="topic-content">
```

I need to retrieve the value of nexttopic

I would think something along the lines of

```
var topicValue = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-nexttopic]").val();
```

Comment: Try attr() instead var topicValue = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("data-nexttopic").val();

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 2 ways

1) using data attribute

```
var topicValue = $(e.relatedTarget).data("nexttopic");
```

2) using normal attribute

```
var topicValue = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("data-nexttopic");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

var topicValue = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-nexttopic');